# How do you convert an NP problem which runs in O(f(x)) time in a SAT instance with O(f(x)*log(f(x))) variables in O(f(x)*log(f(x)))

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I looked at the Cook's theorem at Wikipedia which presents a way to convert any NP problem to SAT but it seems to require O(f(x)^3) variables. Is it possible to remove some of the checks in the conversion so to make it O(f(x)*log(f(x))) in variables and time?

Comment: You can check the material for Lecture 6 from [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/complexity17/) (you can also watch the lecture itself, but IIRC it uses material from previous lectures). I also believe it's $polylog(f)$, not $\log(f)$.

Comment: If I remember correctly how it goes: you have a TM => you construct an oblivious TM (head movement's don't depend on symbols) with polylog overhead => you construct the circuit, where each gate defines a TM transition => you construct a boolean formula for each gate.